# What is the time complexity of given code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
While(n>1)
{
    n=n/20;
    n=n/10;
}
```

**I tried like this =>**

Here, n = n/200
which means that N is getting reduced each time by a factor of 200.
so, time complexity = O(log base 200 N)

Comment: (Bases of logarithms are immaterial in _order of growth_: logarithms to different bases differ by constant factors.)

Comment: @greybeard, yes it is simply O(log N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, n gets reduced to 1/200 each time in the loop.

So, this loop would run log <sub>200</sub> n times.

Hence, time-complexity = O(log <sub>200</sub> n).