# What is the time complexity of the given code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
While(n>=1)
{
    n=n/20;
    n=n/6;
    n=10×n;
    n=n-10000;
}
```

**I tried like this =>**

In this loop, N gets reduced by N/12 - 10000. 
so, time complexity is O(log N).

Comment: If you have an idea what the complexity might be, you can calculate concrete values for some n and compare the resulting graph with the assumed complexity. If both graphs are similar, you can start to find a prove why your assumption is correct.

Comment: thanks! i will keep that in mind

Comment: Please don't post what is basically the same question every few hours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324836/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-given-code). You may want to read a more general Q&A first, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That seems to be correct. If this is an exercise, you should be prepared to argue why `O(log_12(N))`is `O(log(N))`.

Comment: Bases of logarithms are immaterial in order of growth: logarithms to different bases differ by constant factors

Comment: Yes, but can you prove that mathematically?

Comment: I don't know where I get wrong but why isn't it `O(log(N+constant))`?

Comment: @mort, Log base 12 (N) = log base 2 (N) / log base 2 (12) , which simplifies to log base 2 (N)

Comment: @stackuser: yeah, that's it

Comment: @YiFei: The constant is substracted, i.e., it's `O(log(N - constant))`, which is trivially `O(log(N))`.